# Overriding method by another defined in module

Tags: ruby, methods, module

I want to define an instance method `Date#next` which returns the next day. So I made a `DateExtension` module, like this:

```
module DateExtension
  def next(symb=:day)
    dt = DateTime.now
    {:day   => Date.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day + 1),
     :week  => Date.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day + 7),
     :month => Date.new(dt.year, dt.month + 1, dt.day),
     :year  => Date.new(dt.year + 1, dt.month, dt.day)}[symb]
  end
end
```

Using it:

```
class Date
  include DateExtension
end
```

Calling the method `d.next(:week)` makes Ruby throw an error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`.
How can I override the default `next` method from `Date` class with the one declared in `DateExtension` module?

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4470108/520567

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In Ruby 2.0 and later you can use [`Module#prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend):

```ruby
class Date
  prepend DateExtension
end
```

*Original answer for older Ruby versions is below.*

---

The problem with `include` (as shown in [the following diagram](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png)) is that methods of a class cannot be overridden by modules included in that class (solutions follow the diagram):
[image: Ruby Method Lookup Flow]

### Solutions

1. Subclass Date just for this one method:

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> require 'date'; module Foo; def next(a=:hi); a; end; end
   #=> nil
   irb(main):002:0> class MyDate < Date; include Foo; end
   #=> MyDate
   irb(main):003:0> MyDate.today.next(:world)
   #=> :world
   ```
2. Extend just the instances you need with your own method:

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> require 'date'; module Foo; def next(a=:hi); a; end; end
   #=> nil
   irb(main):002:0> d = Date.today; d.extend(Foo); d.next(:world)
   #=> :world
   ```
3. When including your module, perform a gross hack and reach inside the class and destroy the old 'next' so that yours gets called:

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
   #=> true
   irb(main):002:0> module Foo
   irb(main):003:1>   def self.included(klass)
   irb(main):004:2>     klass.class_eval do
   irb(main):005:3*       remove_method :next
   irb(main):006:3>     end
   irb(main):007:2>   end
   irb(main):008:1>   def next(a=:hi); a; end
   irb(main):009:1> end
   #=> nil
   irb(main):010:0> class Date; include Foo; end
   #=> Date
   irb(main):011:0> Date.today.next(:world)
   #=> :world
   ```

   This method is far more invasive than just including a module, but the only way (of the techniques shown so far) to make it so that new Date instances returned by system methods will automatically use methods from your own module.
4. But if you're going to do that, you might as well skip the module altogether and just go straight to monkeypatch land:

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
   #=> true
   irb(main):002:0> class Date
   irb(main):003:1>   alias_method :_real_next, :next
   irb(main):004:1>   def next(a=:hi); a; end
   irb(main):005:1> end
   #=> nil
   irb(main):006:0> Date.today.next(:world)
   #=> :world
   ```
5. If you really need this functionality in your own environment, note that the [Prepend](https://github.com/banister/prepend) library by banisterfiend can give you the ability to cause lookup to occur in a module before the class into which it is mixed.

   - *Note that `Module#prepend` looks to be [coming in Ruby 2.0](http://globaldev.co.uk/2012/11/ruby-2-0-0-preview-features/#id2).*

Comment: RUBY_DESCRIPTION => "ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]"

I just realized something. My code is using the DateTime class, so I need to `require 'date'` (according to [this](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Dates_and_times#Caveat:_you_may_need_to_require_certain_date_classes_for_certain_Date.2FTime_features)). 

Using exactly your example after this instruction, Ruby throws the error. I posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/963819) because I couldn't post the whole code here. Thanks!

Comment: @kaos12 Thanks, I've edited my answer with various options available to you.

Comment: +1 How come I never came across this diagram before? That's amazing, nice work!

Comment: @Jörg Thanks :) There's also a [PDF version](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.pdf) version available.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks a lot! Your answer is very complete and easy to understand. I gotta say that I normally don't mess around with Ruby overriding feature, but after checking your diagram, it makes much more sense. Cheers! Just out of curiosity, is there any reason for this behavior change when using a subclass? Why the method lookup searches first the module?

Comment: @kaos12 There is no change in behavior. Methods from included modules always go 'above' the class they are included into. Try this: `class MyClass; end; [Object,Class,Module,MyClass].each{ |k| k.class_eval{ define_method(:foo){ puts "#{k}#foo"; super() unless k==Object }}}; MyClass.new.foo` Instance methods on a class with no included modules go straight to instance methods on `Object`.

Comment: @Phrogz oh, I see. I find amazing how much you can learn from Ruby community, many thanks mate! ;)

Comment: In the future, [Module#prepend](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/1102) might be worth looking into.

Comment: [Module#prepend](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) is already available in Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 7):

The `next` method for `Date` is defined in the `Date` class and methods defined in a class take precedence over those defined in an included module. So, when you do this:

```
class Date
  include DateExtension
end
```

You're pulling in your version of `next` but the `next` defined in `Date` still takes precedence. You'll have to put your `next` right in `Date`:

```
class Date
  def next(symb=:day)
    dt = DateTime.now
      {:day   => Date.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day + 1),
       :week  => Date.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day + 7),
       :month => Date.new(dt.year, dt.month + 1, dt.day),
       :year  => Date.new(dt.year + 1, dt.month, dt.day)}[symb]
    end
end
```

From the the Programming Ruby chapter on [Classes and Objects](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/classes.html#UC):

> When a class includes a module, that module's instance methods become available as instance methods of the class. It's almost as if the module becomes a superclass of the class that uses it. Not surprisingly, that's about how it works. When you include a module, Ruby creates an anonymous proxy class that references that module, and inserts that proxy as the direct superclass of the class that did the including.