# Why doesn't const_missing work without prefixing it with Object?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

It looks like `const_missing` is an instance method of `Object`. If so, why doesn't this code work?

```
module Extensions
  def const_missing(c)
    puts c
  end
end

class Object
  include Extensions
end

NonExistent.new
```

In order to get it to function correctly, I have to change `def const_missing` to `def Object.const_missing`. Why?

Comment: Because proper methods are called before included Modules.

Comment: What do you mean "proper methods"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding method by another defined in module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944278/overriding-method-by-another-defined-in-module)

Comment: See the duplicate that I've linked to. That explains that modules' methods are searched after methods of the class itself (but before ancestor methods), and also mentions some possible workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the way method calls are resolved in Ruby.

First, singleton methods are checked. Then instance methods of the class, followed by the ancestors (which will be the included modules, then superclasses with their included modules).

So you could define `Object.const_missing` directly, or include your Module in the singleton class of Object:

```
class << Object
  include Extensions
end

NonExistent # => prints "NonExistent"
```

You could also monkeypatch `Module#const_missing`.