# Can I overwrite instance method from module?

Tags: ruby, overwrite

I know, I can overwrite class method from module this way

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def some_static_method
      puts 'some_static_method'
    end
  end
end

module BAR
  class << Foo
    def some_static_method
      puts 'another_static_method'
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include BAR
end

Foo.some_static_method # => 'another_static_method'
```

Is it possible for an instance method?

Comment: You might find some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944278/overriding-method-by-another-defined-in-module).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
class Foo
  def self.some_static_method; puts "Hello from Foo" end
end

module Bar
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_eval do
     def some_static_method; puts "Hello from Bar" end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar
end

Foo.some_static_method
```

This should work

**UPDATE**

To override instance method use:

```
class Foo
  def some_instance_method; puts "Hello from Foo" end
end

module Bar
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
     def some_instance_method; puts "Hello from Bar" end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar
end

Foo.new.some_instance_method
```

Comment: Ok. It's more elegant way to overwrite class method. so, what about instance method of the Foo class?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually not about method overriding. It is about what class is referred to within a `class ...` construction in a module body.

When you do

```
module Bar
  class << Foo
    p self
  end
end
# => #<Class:Foo>
```

the `<< Foo` points to the singleton class of the `Foo` in the main environment because `class << Foo` cannot define the singleton class directly of a class `Foo` that has not been defined in advance. So it looks up for `Foo` that is already defined, and such class is found in the main environment.

When you do

```
module Bar
  class Foo
    p self
  end
end
# => Bar::Foo
```

a new class `Bar::Foo` is created; the `Foo` points to this `Bar::Foo` that is newly created, and it does not point to the `Foo` in the main environment. In order to point to it, you have to explicitly specify that with `::`.

```
module Bar
  class ::Foo
    p self
  end
end
# => Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby > 2.0.0 then what you can use is `Module#prepend`. Instead of `include` you can `prepend` an module and that way all of the module's methods are overriding any existing class instance methods with the same name. You can see a quick example [here](http://dev.af83.com/2012/10/19/ruby-2-0-module-prepend.html).

Prior to Ruby 2, Rails had introduced a similar hack: [`#alias_method_chain`](http://codelevy.com/2013/02/26/ruby2.0-vs-alias_method_chain.html)

[Here](http://codelevy.com/2013/02/26/ruby2.0-vs-alias_method_chain.html) is a nice comparison of the two approaches.