# Hash for ActiveRecord's select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to pass a `Hash` as a parameter for the `ActiveRecord`'s `select`? I mean like this (here I have simple model: `LineItem` has `id`'s of `Product` and `Order`):

```
Product.select(
    :orders => [{:name => :buyer}, :email], # orders.name as buyer
    :products => {:title => :product}).     # products.title as product
  joins(:line_items => :order)
```

To get the following SQL:

```
SELECT "orders"."name" as "buyer", "orders"."email", "products"."title" as "product" 
FROM "products"
INNER JOIN "line_items" ON "line_items"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "line_items"."order_id"
```

If it isn't possible, then I suggest some **backward-compatible** (can be used in old way, with 1 simple string as a peremeter) extension for the `select` method, but I can't figure out how to make it as **transparent** (i.e. w/o `_h` at the end as I did below) application-wide replacement:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.select_h(*fields) # TODO: rid of this ugly _h
    hash_of_fields = fields.last.is_a?(Hash) ? fields.pop : {}
    fields_in_hash = hash_of_fields.map do |table, field_or_fields|
      (field_or_fields.is_a?(Array) ? field_or_fields : [field_or_fields]).map do |field|
        field = "#{field.first[0]}\" as \"#{field.first[1]}" if field.is_a? Hash
        "\"#{table}\".\"#{field}\""
      end
    end
    # calling original select
    select (fields+fields_in_hash).join(', ')
  end
end
```

**I'll appreciate pointing me at some details about internals of `ActiveRecord`'s implementation regarding it's pattern that was used to make this very obscure-to-exam gem :)**

Answer (score 1):

The source of the select method--

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb, line 34
def select(value = Proc.new)
  if block_given?
    to_a.select {|*block_args| value.call(*block_args) }
  else
    relation = clone
    relation.select_values += Array.wrap(value)
    relation
  end
end
```

-- suggests that it won't do what you're asking it to. However, as it can optionally take a block you might be able to coerce it into the behavior you're looking for...

Whenever I get confused about what I can and can't do with the Arel stuff, I just peruse the source at:

[Arel API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select)

I'm not sure this helps but at the very least it might send you in the right direction to explore...

Comment: Snippet shows that the block for `select` was designed mostly for testing purposes: `select` with a block just fetches all the rows from respective table (via exhaustive `SELECT * FROM table`) into an array and applies `Array#select` to it, thus filtering it using Ruby language rather than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For your final question of how to avoid the _h, see [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'Hello'
  end
end 

class Foo
  old_bar = instance_method(:bar)

  define_method(:bar) do
    old_bar.bind(self).() + ' World'
  end
end

Foo.new.bar # => 'Hello World'
```