# monkey patching vs class_eval?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, monkeypatching

```
class String
  def hello
    "world"
  end
end

String.class_eval {
  def world
    "hello"
  end
}

"a".world
=> "hello"
"b".hello
=> "world"
```

They seems to do the same thing -- adding a method to a existing class. So what's the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `class_eval` you can do more dynamic things:

```
>> met = "hello" #=> "hello"
>> String.class_eval "def #{met} ; 'hello' ; end" #=> nil
>> "foo".hello #=> "hello"
```

Comment: Complicated example.

Answer (score 14):

class_eval do conceptually class reopening (or monkey patching). There are mostly syntactic differences. If you pass string to `class_eval` (as in Michael's example) you have mostly the same syntax inside the string as in `class String; ... end`. If you pass block: `String.class_eval { ... }` it compares as follows:

- inside class_eval block outer local variables are visible
- inside reopened class outer local variables are NOT visible
- inside class_eval you CANNOT assign constants and class variables scoped to the class
- inside reopened class you CAN

It would be interesting to know the other differences

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are good. Want to add that `class_eval` can be used when you want reference class not by its constant or to patch particular object.

e.g.

```
huh = String
class huh
end
SyntaxError: (eval):2: class/module name must be CONSTANT

huh.class_eval <<-eof
def mamma
puts :papa
end
eof

"asdff".mamma
=> papa
```

You can use `class_eval` to patch particular object without affectin whole root class.

```
obj = "asd"
obj.singleton_class.class_eval <<-eof
def asd
puts "gah"
end
undef_method :some_method
```

The above is same as:

```
class << obj
  ...
end
```

`instance_eval` will have slightly different behavior by some usage.

I find this question and answers interesting:
[How to monkey patch a ruby class inside a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666061/how-to-monkey-patch-a-ruby-class-inside-a-method)

Also there were questions about `instance_eval` vs `class_eval` but I don't have a link handy.