# What's the best way to add functionality to a swig generated ruby module?

Tags: ruby

I have successfully generated a ruby module from a compiled c++ library, but I want to add some ruby methods.  For example one of the libraries returns a linked list of objects that you access via:

```
objects.get_first_object
objects.get_next_object
```

I would like to add a method so I can do

```
objects.each do |object| 
  ...
end
```

so probably something like

```
def to_a
  ret = Array.new
  obj = objects.get_first_object
  while obj
    ret << obj
    obj = objects.get_next_object
  end
  return ret
end
```

The question is not how to create the methods but how should I add them to the class?

Should I just open the classes and add the methods?
I was thinking of creating subclasses but that seems messy since there is inheritance involved, so I think if I do that I would have to re-create the inheritance?

If I decide to open the classes, what the best way to to that?

Comment: *Should I just open the classes and add the methods?* yes you can do that.

Comment: see [Recommended approach to monkey patching a class in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337712/recommended-approach-to-monkey-patching-a-class-in-ruby) or more [ruby monkey patch class](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ruby+monkey+patch+class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZR61UpSkOMePrQeAo4HQDw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the class and add the method:

```
class SwigGeneratedClass
  def to_a
    ret = Array.new
    obj = objects.get_first_object
    while obj
      ret << obj
      obj = objects.get_next_object
    end
    return ret
  end
end
```

There's no reason to do anything fancier.

Comment: I decided to go with SwigGeneratedClass.class_eval do ... There seem to be a few case were that method was slightly better, but the above is fine in my case as well.

Comment: @nPn: just note that its not idomatic to use class_eval for this.