# How to monkey patch a ruby class inside a method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming, monkeypatching

I am unable to monkey patch a class inside a method body.

Within a method definition, 
I am trying to use a class in two ways:

1] Create an instance and use the orignal definition of a method in the class I am using

2] Monkey patch (pverride) a method in the class and now use an instance with the new method definition.

Basically I would be using both of the above instances of a class in my program.

The challenge is the method I am overriding gets called during initialization so I have to override it before I create the instance of the class.

Here is a small mock-up:

```
class A

  def initialize
   do_something
  end

  def do something
     #implementation
  end

end
```

Now , I want to use A in the same method twice , but once by using a modified version of do_something
This is how I am trying to do it:

```
def my_method

  orig_instance = A.new

  #patch the class
  Class A          # ERROR: CLASS DEF IN METHOD BODY
   class << self
     alias_method :old_do_something, :do_something

     def self.do_something
        # new implementation
     end
  end

  new_instance = A.new

  #restore method
   class << self
     alias_method :do_something,:old_do_something

     def self.do_something
        # new implementation
     end
  end        



end # end of method
```

I get the (ERROR: CLASS DEF IN METHOD BODY) where I try to monkey patch the class, since I am trying to change the class inside of a method.

How do I achieve monkey patching the class in a method ?

Thanks

Comment: You get the error above? Which error? And it's c, not C for class.

Comment: Sorry, if you skimmed over the code , you could miss the ERROR marked in the code. Writing it again for clarity

Comment: slightly unrelated but i'm pretty sure `//` doesn't mark a comment in ruby

Comment: I changed some wording of the question to make it more clear. Hopefully this could be re-opened since its a real programming question and something I need for a real use-case. Thanks

Comment: There's nothing unclear in this question!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `class Clazz; blabla; end` to reopen `Clazz` and monkey patch it, you can use `Module#class_eval`, `Module#instance_eval` and some other meta-programming utilities/methods to do the same trick. And because that block accepted by these methods doesn't create new binding scopes, it is more convenient in meta-programming practice.

```rb
def my_method
  puts ">> creating orig_instance"
  orig_instance = A.new

  puts ">> dump orig_instance"
  orig_instance.do_something

  new_do_something = lambda do
    puts "Modified A#do_something"
  end

  # monkey patch class A so that the modified version of do_something get called
  # during initialization of new_instance
  A.class_eval do
    alias_method :old_do_something, :do_something
    define_method :do_something, new_do_something
  end

  puts ">> creating new_instance"
  new_instance = A.new

  puts ">> dump before do_something gets restored"
  new_instance.do_something
  orig_instance.do_something

  # add singleton method for the special instance
  # so that the instance always calls the modified do_something
  new_instance_singleton = class << new_instance; self end
  new_instance_singleton.send :define_method, :do_something, new_do_something

  # restore the modified do_something
  # so that orig_instance and all other instances (except new_instance) have the original definition
  A.class_eval do
    alias_method :do_something, :old_do_something
  end
  puts ">> dump for final result"
  new_instance.do_something
  orig_instance.do_something
end
```

And the following is the output of `my_method` call:

```
>> creating orig_instance
Original A#do_something
>> dump orig_instance
Original A#do_something
>> creating new_instance
Modified A#do_something
>> dump before do_something gets restored
Modified A#do_something
Modified A#do_something
>> dump for final result
Modified A#do_something
Original A#do_something
```

Comment: Thanks @Arie. Can you please explain why its necessary to add the singleton instance given that Class A is already monkey patched to use the new method definition. It not clear to me what "class << new_instance; self end" is doing especially after the new instance is already created.

Comment: @codeObserver I thought you want to make changes to the instance method of a special instance (starting from creation and lasting for the whole life time of the instance). If you restore the method without monkey patching for the special `new_instance`, `new_instance` will use the original implementation of the methods after restoring. The monkey patch to the singleton instance makes the new method be used in the whole lifetime of `new_instance`. If you just want to alter the behavior during creation, you can omit the patch to the singleton class.

Comment: @codeObserver `class << new_instance; self end` returns the eigenclass (or singleton class, ~Google it~) of the `new_instance`. That's a special class associated to the very `new_instance`. All the methods defined in that class will only be visible to `new_instance`. So that's the way to monkey patch a given instance rather than all instance of a given class.

Comment: I don't know if my question fits this thread, but I think #class_eval does not work for me, as, I want to redefine a method of a class that uses a class-constant:  In your example, `A.class_eval` closes over the scope of #my_method while `class A` would close over the scope of class A. Thus, if in my redefined method, I try to access a (class-)constant defined in A, I will get a "uninitialized constant" error with #class_eval. That's why, I'm still wondering, how can I monkey-patch a class A inside of a method, like I would do with re-opening `class A`?