# How can I redefine Fixnum's + (plus) method in Ruby and keep original + functionality?

Tags: ruby, super, rubinius, yarv

This throws me a SystemStackError in 1.9.2 Ruby (<strike>but works in Rubinius</strike>):

```
class Fixnum
  def +(other)
   self + other * 2
  end
end
```

but there is no `super` for `+` (based on other errors).

How can I access the original `+` functionality?

Comment: Wait, you're saying this works as you expect in Rubinius?

Comment: I just tested it, doesn't work in Rubinius. The overridden method is just ignored.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? That's a loaded fully automatic foot gun right there.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious from the question, but this is a duplicate (or rather a special case) of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://StackOverflow.Com/a/4471202/2988/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

Comment: Don't do this! But do read @JörgWMittag 's answer at the linked question!

Comment: I just wanted to use this as a testing ground, but as I see it was not a good idea to modify a method almost everything depends on...

Comment: There. Are. Four. Lights! +1 (or is that +3?)

Comment: @muistooshort: it's an exercise from [a book](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `alias_method`. Alias `Fixnum`'s `+` to something else, then refer to it in the new `+`:

```
class Fixnum
  alias_method :old_add, :+
  def +(other)
    self.old_add(other) * 2
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, doing this seems to really confuse my IRb somehow, but does in fact work in plain Ruby.

Comment: @NiklasB. I usually try and refrain from editing answers within the first few minutes. And people seem to mix up the syntax for `alias` vs. `alias_method` a lot.

Comment: @Andrew: I am not suprised to hear that *overriding freakin' integer addition* doesn't go down too well for the IRb... This is so bad a hack that I can barely describe it through words.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yea, when I do `end` for the `class` it returns nothing—not `nil` *nothing*, as in blank. Trying to look at `_` yields the same: *nothing*. Agreed that this is a horribly bad idea, but interesting solution.

Comment: Is this a good practice? I really need to do something like this, but all common sense tells me this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting approach would be to pass a block to Fixnum's `module_eval` method. So, for instance:

```
module FixnumExtend
  puts '..loading FixnumExtend module'

  Fixnum.module_eval do |m|
    alias_method :plus,     :+
    alias_method :min,      :-
    alias_method :div,      :/
    alias_method :mult,     :*
    alias_method :modu,     :%
    alias_method :pow,      :**

    def sqrt
     Math.sqrt(self)
    end

  end

end
```

Now, after including FixnumExtend throughout my app I can do:

```
2.plus 2   
=> 4

81.sqrt
=> 9
```

I am using this approach to help my OCR engine recognize handwritten code. It has an easier time with `2.div 2` than `2/2`.