# Ruby override class method

Tags: ruby, class

Is it possible to, for example, override the 'puts' method and replace it with a function that calls 'puts' twice?

For example:

```
class IO
  def puts str
    puts str
    puts str
  end
end
```

I know this example is stupid but I need it for something else.  Basically, I want to override a function but I want the overriding function to include calls to the original, overridden function.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to override this in the same class as it is defined, instead of subclassing or mixing in a method on the instances?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class IO

  alias puts_orig puts
  def puts str
    puts_orig str
    puts_orig str
  end
end
```