# No superclass method when calling super in define_method

Tags: ruby

- Why do I get the following error `talk: super: no superclass method talk (NoMethodError)` when I override a method that already exists?
- How could I fix this code to call the super method?

Here is the sample code I'm using

```
class Foo
  def talk(who, what, where)
    p "#{who} is #{what} at #{where}" 
  end
end

Foo.new.talk("monster", "jumping", "home")

class Foo
  define_method(:talk) do |*params|
    super(*params)
  end
end

Foo.new.talk("monster", "jumping", "home")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i/4471202#4471202

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because you overwrite #talk. Try this

```
class Foo
  def talk(who, what, where)
    p "#{who} is #{what} at #{where}" 
  end
end

Foo.new.talk("monster", "jumping", "home")

class Bar < Foo
  define_method(:talk) do |*params|
    super(*params)
  end
end

Bar.new.talk("monster", "table", "home")
```

Comment: He's ovewriting `#foo` rather than overriding `#foo`.

Comment: I mean `#talk`, not `#foo`.

Comment: Thanks. My brain wasn't working correctly. I thought it was something to do with the way I was using `define_method`.