# How to overwrite the system function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'ld like to overwrite the system() function. Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you do that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You could "monkeypatch" it, symply by defining it, as commentor 23tux explains. But you [really don't want to overwrite the system(). Really not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/73673).

Comment: This is a bad thing to do. That you ask if you can shows you probably don't know why you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can overwrite nearly everything in Ruby (whether useful or not):

```
system "ls /" # returns "/etc /var...", normal behaviour

def system args
  puts args
end

system "ls /" # returns "ls /"
```

Comment: I don't know your project, but if you want to use it global: Before you are calling system the first time ;) In an initializer for example, or in your startscript or whatever

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't matter to use `system` at all then you can use backticks. The backticks execute the command and return the output as a string.

You can then assign the value to a variable like so:

```
output = `ls`
p output
```