# Add functionality to a method by overriding, but still call original method

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

So I wish to simply add some conditional checks to a method by overriding it, but then I want the original method to be called.  How does one do this in ruby?

ie.

method exists

```
def fakeMethod(cmd)
  puts "#{cmd}"
end
```

and I want to add

```
if (cmd) == "bla"
  puts "caught cmd"
else
  fakeMethod(cmd)
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
alias :old_fake_method :fake_method
def fake_method(cmd)
  if (cmd) == "bla"
    puts "caught cmd"
  else
    old_fake_method(cmd)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use inheritance. It is a classical example overridden methods are augmented with additional logic:

```
class Foo
  def foo(cmd)
    puts cmd
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def foo(cmd)
    if cmd == "hello"
      puts "They want to say hello!"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

Foo.new.foo("bar")   # => prints "bar"
Bar.new.foo("hello") # => prints "They want to say hello"
```

Sure, this solution only works if you have a chance to instantiate a subclass instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is [alias_method_chain](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain) and [alias](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method)_method in ruby for this.

(alias_method_chain is not in ruby, but in ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions, so you minght need to require that if this isn't a rails application)