# How to set a timeout in deploy_revision provider?

Tags: chef-infra

I found a situation when chef had generated Chef::Exceptions::CommandTimeout exception in git clone command. Sometimes the time of git clone could be more than 10 minutes. How to set the timeout value for such situations in chef recipe?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 6):

Timeout for the git provider seems to be fixed now.

Checkout the code at: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/git.rb#L292

So for the git resource you can just add the `timeout` attribute, i.e.:

```
git /var/www do
  repository <githubrepo>
  action :sync
  user www-data
  group www-data
  timeout 1200
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way of changing timeout, I mean by passing some attributes. You will have to overwrite run_options method in [git provider](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/git.rb). Check out [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i) for different possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here. thanks for the hint. was able to write the monkey patch like so:

https://gist.github.com/mikesmullin/5660466