# How to increase deploy timeout limit at AWS Opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I would like to increase the deploy time, in a stack layer that hosts many apps (AWS Opsworks). 
Currenlty I get the following error:

**Eror**

```
[2014-05-05T22:27:51+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-05-05T22:27:51+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-05-05T22:27:51+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-05-05T22:27:51+00:00] ERROR: deploy[/srv/www/lakers_test] (opsworks_delayed_job::deploy line 65) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: Command timed out after 600s:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a timeout in deploy\_revision provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557118/how-to-set-a-timeout-in-deploy-revision-provider)

Comment: different kind of error, different kind of solution, but similar topics (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as mentioned [in this ticket](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/issues/133) reporting a similar issue, the Opsworks guys recommend trying to speed up the call first (there's always room for optimization).

If that doesn't work, we can go down the rabbit hole: [this gets called](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/dbca69153bf9157bfca5034e957cdb75e67bd396/opsworks_commons/libraries/shellout.rb), which in turn calls [`Mixlib::ShellOut.new`](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout/blob/master/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb#L157), which happens to have a [timeout option](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout/blob/master/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb#L128) that you can pass in the initializer!

Now you can use an **Opsworks custom cookbook** to overwrite the initial method, and pass the corresponding **timeout option**. Opsworks merges the contents of its [base cookbooks](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks) with the contents of your custom cookbook - therefore you only need to add & edit one single file to your custom cookbook: `opsworks_commons/libraries/shellout.rb`:

```
module OpsWorks
  module ShellOut
    extend self

    # This would be your new default timeout.
    DEFAULT_OPTIONS = { timeout: 900 }

    def shellout(command, options = {})
      cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(command, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge(options))
      cmd.run_command
      cmd.error!
      [cmd.stderr, cmd.stdout].join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

Notice how the only additions are just `DEFAULT_OPTIONS` and merging these options in the `Mixlib::ShellOut.new` call.

An improvement to this method would be changing this timeout option via a **chef attribute**, that you could in turn update via your *custom JSON* in the Opsworks interface. This means passing the `timeout` attribute in the initial `Opsworks::ShellOut.shellout` call - not in the method definition. But this depends on how the `shellout` method actually gets called...

Comment: Did anyone actually try this? I've tried numerous variations - putting the code in my cookbook at opsworks_commons/libraries/shellout.rb, putting it at the top of my actual recipe etc but all without any luck in increasing the timeout limit.

I actually put a log message in the shellout method, and it doesn't seem to be getting called at all. 

Thoughts?

Comment: It did work for us. Did you call the "update custom cookbooks" command after every update to your custom cookbooks repository? It's under `Stack -> Run command -> "Update custom cookbooks"` and your custom cookbook code needs to be pushed to your remote repository obviously.

What errors did you encounter?

Comment: I'm using cloudformation, and ran the entire template again, setting up a new stack. I definitely have the updated chef code running (as I put log statements in which get hit), but it always times out setting up Java. 

I've found that I can get around the problem by using a bigger instance, but it'd be good to know how to configure it by hand. 

If you've got a public example, please share! p.s. I'm using Chef 11.10 - but it looks like this code would still be valid for that version.