# Is monkey patching PageObject::PageFactory#visit_page a good idea?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, page-object-gem

A developer recently asked if our tests could execute some javascript every time a page is opened. See [bug 44299](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44299) for more details.

Executing javascript is trivial:

```
browser.execute_script('return mw.loader.getModuleNames().filter(function (module) { return mw.loader.getState(module) === "error"; }).length === 0;')
#=> true
```

We are using [page-object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object)'s [`#visit_page`](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/page_factory.rb#L52-L54) to open pages. An easy way to make sure the javascript in the above example is executed every time a page is opened would be to monkey patch the `#visit_page` method.

`alias_method` chain (from question [4470108](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/17469)) looks like a simple way to do it.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a method on your page object class named `initialize_page`.  This method will be called immediately after the page loads.  In that method you can make the call to `execute_script` (a method on the page) passing the javascript you wish to execute.

Comment: But then I would have to do it in every page, right? Monkey patching would make it possible to run the javascript on every page.

Comment: Monkey patching would do it and would make it easy to remove it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are doing a bit too much work for something very simple. I'm not sure what framework you are using, but do you have an application wide JavaScript file? For a rails application I would write a test.js.erb:

```
<%= %q+browser.execute_script('return mw.loader.getModuleNames().filter(function (module) { return mw.loader.getState(module) === "error"; }).length === 0;')+ if Rails.env.test? %>
```

and add `//= test` to your application manifest