# Why does method not returning its last expression when it is called?

Tags: ruby

I was playing with the last expression returned by the method,when it is being invoked via an object.

With the concept below code works.

```
class Simple
  def foo
    2 + 2
  end
end
#=> nil
simple = Simple.new
#=> #<Simple:0x11eb390>
simple.foo
#=> 4
```

But why the below code returns such encoded value rather than `15` and `20`?

```
class Fixnum
  def to_s
    self + 5
  end
end
#=> nil
puts 10
#<Fixnum:0x000015>
#=> nil
puts 15
#<Fixnum:0x00001f>
#=> nil
```

Can anyone help me here to understand the concept?

**Edit:**

```
class Fixnum
  def to_s
    self + 5
  end
end
#=> nil
10.to_s
#=> #<Fixnum:0x000029>
```

Again the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contract of `to_s` requires that you return a `String`. You are, however, returning a `Fixnum`. If you violate a contract, all sorts of weird things may happen.

If you correctly return a `String` from your `to_s` method, everything works as you might expect:

```
class Fixnum
  def to_s
    "#{self + 5}"
  end
end

puts 10
# SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Well, okay, "everything works" may have been a bit misleading. But, as you can see, everything *happens* as you might expect it: `puts` calls `to_s` on `10`, which adds `5` to `10` returning `15`, then it calls `to_s` on `15`, which adds `5` returning `20`, then calls `to_s` on `20` etc.

```
class Fixnum
  orig_to_s = public_instance_method(:to_s)

  define_method(:to_s) do
    orig_to_s.bind(self + 5).()
  end
end

puts 10
# 15
```

*Now*, everything works as expected.

Comment: @DoLoveSky: See the section titled *Method Wrapping* in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988

Answer (score 0):

If you add 5 to self, you get another Fixnum.

When you print the Fixnum whose to_s you have modified not to show the result, you started seeing the resulting object instead of the value of fixnum.