# Overriding the =~ operator of Regexp in a subclass Subregex, result in a weird behaviour when executing "example" =~ subregexex

Tags: ruby, regex, operators

Given the following example in Ruby 2.0.0:

```
class Regexp
  def self.build
    NumRegexp.new("-?[\d_]+")
  end
end

class NumRegexp < Regexp
  def match(value)
    'hi two'
  end
  def =~(value)
    'hi there'
  end
end

var_ex = Regexp.build
var_ex =~ '12'   # => "hi there" , as expected
'12' =~  var_ex  # => nil , why? It was expected "hi there" or "hi two"
```

According to the documentation of Ruby of the `=~` operator for the class `String`:

> str =~ obj → fixnum or nil
>
> "If obj is a Regexp, use it as a pattern to match against str,and returns the position the match starts, or nil if there is no match. Otherwise, invokes obj.=~, passing str as an argument. The default =~ in Object returns nil."
>
> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E

It is a fact that the variable `var_ex` is an object of class `NumRegexp`, hence, it is not a `Regexp` object. Therefore, it should invoke the method `obj.=~` passing the string as an argument, as indicated in the documentation and returning `"hi there"`.

In another case, maybe as `NumRegexp` is a subclass of `Regexp` it could be considered a `Regexp` type. Then, "If obj is a Regexp use it as a pattern to match against str". It should return `"hi two"` in that case.

What is wrong in my reasoning? What do I have to do to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the record:

```
var_ex =~ '12'
```

isn't the same of:

```
'12' =~  var_ex
```

It seems that there are no [string](/questions/tagged/string) method that calls to [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) class `#~=` method back, this is a bug already [reported](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8953), and expected to be solved in *2.2.0*. So you have to declare it explicitly:

```
class String
   alias :__system_match :=~ 
   def =~ regex
      regex.is_a?( Regexp ) && ( regex =~ self ) || __system_match( regex )
   end
end

'12' =~ /-?[\d_]+/
# => 0
```

This is a [possible and acceptable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i) using monkey patching but it presents some problems to take into account:

> The problem with this is that we have now polluted the namespace with a superfluous `__system_match` method. This method will show up in our documentation, it will show up in code completion in our IDEs, it will show up during reflection. Also, it still can be called, but presumably we monkey patched it, because we didn't like its behavior in the first place, so we might not want other people to call it.

Comment: "It seems there are no string method that calls to Regexp class #~= method back". In the documentation, it can be read the source of the method implementation. As I understand, it is calling the Regexp methods: in this line "return rb_reg_match(y, x);" when it is a Regexp obj, and in this one "return rb_funcall(y, rb_intern("=~"), 1, x);", when it is another object type. Although, I appreciate your answer, I am asking why this has not the behaviour that should be expected from the documentation.

Comment: If you try modifying the Regexp's code it has the same behaviour. 

I found it is a bug already reported:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8953

Comment: I updated your answer, i hope you are ok with the changes, i did my best,

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that  you are calling `=~` method on a string, not on your NumRegexp object. You need to tell String how to behave:

```
class String
  def =~(reg)
    return reg=~self if reg.is_a? NumRegexp
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: I think It won't work as expected, as when calling super , it will try to call the superclass of string method, not the previous method. The solution by Малъ Скрылевъ, implements this right. Although, Ruby keeps having a weird behaviour

Comment: @DavidDíazClavijo - When you override the method it points to the previous implementation. Try it in irb.

Comment: class String
  def to_s
    'hello' + super
  end
end

a = String.new ('abc')
puts a.to_s  # => hello#<String:0x007f437e9c70c0> but expected was : helloabc