# Trying to alias old method and create new one in ruby

Tags: ruby, respond-to

I'm using the following snippet to only alias the method if the method exists:

```
alias_method old_name, func_name if self.respond_to? func_name
```

How can it Error with `alias_method': undefined method 'get' for class 'Sinatra::Base' (NameError)` when `self.respond_to? func_name` returns true?

`func_name = :get` in this snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good answer to my problem here at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

Instead of monkey patching the original class I instead create a module and then use `prepend` and just call `super` to call the original method.
I now do this:

```
Sinatra::Base.prepend Restman::Patches::Sinatra_Base_Patch
```

With the module `Sinatra_Base_Patch` containing the function that overwrites the original.

The example I followed is this:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'Hello'
  end
end 

module FooExtensions
  def bar
    super + ' World'
  end
end

class Foo
  prepend FooExtensions # the only change to above: prepend instead of include
end

Foo.new.bar # => 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet you call `alias_method` inside the scope of `Sinatra::Base`. You should call it inside the **singleton class** of `Sinatra::Base`, because the method `get` is defined as a class method.

Comment: AH! you would be right, I see, I can't believe I missed that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
alias_method :new_name, :func_name
```

E.g., you have a name attribute in a record:

```
alias_method :to_s, :name
```

Comment: `old_name` & `func_name` are variables storing values, in this case: `old_name = :old_get` & `func_name = :get`.  Oddly when I try to instead store the old method as an `UnBoundMethod` using `instance_method(func_name)` it errors with the same Error (that the method doesn't exist) however doing `puts Sinatra::Base.methods.sort.to_s` shows that the method `:get` does indeed exist.