# What the purpose of bind/unbind methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

What is the purpose of having `Method#unbind` and `UnboundMethod#bind`?

From what I gather, methods are callable objects like procs and lambdas, except that methods are bound to the scope of their receiver:

```
class SomeClass
  def a_method; puts "from SomeClass"; end
end

s = SomeClass.new
s.a_method # => "from SomeClass"
```

I can call `a_method` if I'm within the context of `SomeClass` or if I have an object of `SomeClass`. I can make it a callable object by extracting the method as a `Method` object, yet it's still bound to an object of class `SomeClass` in this example:

```
m = s.method :a_method
m.class # => Method
m.owner # => SomeClass
m.call # => "from SomeClass"
```

Why would I want to `unbind` a method from its receiver? Maybe I can pass this around or `bind` it to a different object giving it new context, maybe I can have a completely different object call this method without inheritance, but I can't do anything with it unless I bind it to an object of its original class or I convert it to a `Proc` object (really a lambda, since methods and lambdas are somewhat similar):

```
# Module#instance_method gives me an UnboundMethod
ub = SomeClass.instance_method :a_method
ub.class # -> UnboundMethod

# now I can't make any calls 
ub.call # -> NoMethod Error, undefined method 'call'

class AnotherClass; end
a = AnotherClass.new
b = ub.bind(a) # -> TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of SomeClass
b = ub.bind(SomeClass.new).call # -> "from SomeClass"
```

I could convert the method object into a proc and maybe do something with it:

```
AnotherClass.class_eval do
  # I can access m becausec this block is evaluated in the same 
  # scope it's defined, so I can grab m ;)
  define_method(:method_from_some_class, m.to_proc)
end

AnotherClass.instance_methods(false) # -> [:method_from_some_class]
a.method_from_some_class # -> "from SomeClass"
```

What is the purpose of doing this? What are the real world applications for something like this?

Comment: Welp... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708250/what-is-the-point-of-rubys-method-unbinding-mechanism

Comment: I understand what they do,, but I will say that in 8 years of ruby programming, including occasional reflective metaprorgramming cleverness, I've never had to use `bind` on an unbound method, or done much with an unbound method at all. They are rarely needed. But good that they are there for complete reflective control in ruby.  If you aren't seeing a use for them though, it's because the uses are rare for tricky things you'll know when you have one. If it's part of your day-to-day toolbox, you're probably being way too clever.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is indeed useful for metaprogramming. Suppose you want to know the location of the source code for `SomeClass#method`. If you can generate an instance of `SomeClass`, then you can create a (bound) method instance of it on that `SomeClass` instance, on which you can call various methods to investigate some meta-data of the method. But what if you did not know the method signature of `SomeClass#new`, or what if `SomeClass`'s constructor method was named other than `SomeClass#new`? Just safely creating an instance of  `SomeClass` can be difficult. That is where unbound method comes in handy. Without bothering with a particular instance of the class, or with how to create an instance, you can simply do `SomeClass.instance_method(:a_method)` (which is an unbound method), then call `source_location` on it to investigate the location of the definition:

```
unbound = SomeClass.instance_method(:a_method)
puts unbound.source_location
```

And when would this kind of metaprogramming be necessary in the real world applications? One example is when you are creating an IDE with functions for method lookup.