# Override Rails has_secure_password's authenticate method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm using a combination of a custom user database with `has_secure_password` and active dirctory for authentication. If a user is marked as an Active Directory user then I'll authenticate against AD, otherwise against the database.

I want to overide `has_secure_password`'s `authenticate` method to reflect that.

**I know I can handle it in the controller or though a new method that calls `authenticate`, but would prefer a proper override**

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Here is how I make the validation work out, if that matters:
  has_secure_password :validations => false
  validates :active_directory_user, presence: true, unless: :password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: :active_directory_user
  validates :password_digest, presence: true, unless: :active_directory_user

  # Here is what I want to do
  def authenticate(pass)
    if self.active_directory_user
      active_directory_auth(pass)
    else
      # this doesn't work, I need to somehow reference the non-overriden function
      self.authenticate(pass)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. I needed to use some monkey patching as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i). I used the **Method Wrapping** section's suggestions.

The end result is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Must have either password or be a active directory user
  has_secure_password :validations => false
  validates :active_directory_user, presence: true, unless: :password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: :active_directory_user
  validates :password_digest, presence: true, unless: :active_directory_user

  # Mokey patch on authenticate to use active directory
  old_autheticate = instance_method(:authenticate)
  define_method(:authenticate) do |pass|
    if self.active_directory_user
      active_directory_auth(pass)
    else
      old_autheticate.bind(self).(pass)
    end
  end

  private
    def active_directory_auth (password)
      domain = "domain"
      ldap = Net::LDAP.new
      ldap.host = '<ad ip>'
      ldap.port = 389
      ldap.auth self.username + "@" + domain, password
      if ldap.bind
        self
      else
        false
      end
    end
end
```