# Don't delete impressions when soft deleting a record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, impressions, impressionist

I'm using **impressionist gem** to lock the views for different products. I'm also having **soft-deletion** in my application. When I remove any record/product, its impressions also got deleted.

I just want to keep the impressions and don't want to delete it on Record deletion. Any idea, how i can do it ?

using

```
ruby 2.2.2
Rails 4.2.4
impressionist (1.5.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [test](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/729e4fca3ba414842fbf357b8b18bcbdf2ee2371/tests/test_app/spec/models/model_spec.rb#L61) it's the expected behaviour.

Now I would try to [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/5006469) this [method](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/729e4fca3ba414842fbf357b8b18bcbdf2ee2371/lib/impressionist/is_impressionable.rb#L15) in order to remove the `destroy` dependance.

Comment: Thanks @standelaune. going to try this also.