# List of decorated methods when using draper decorators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator

I need way to get an array of names of all decorated methods created in a **[draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)** decorator instance.

If i have two classes like:

```
class A
  def foo
  end
end

class ADecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def bar
  end

  def hi
  end
end
```

Then i want to do something like:

```
decorated = ADecorator.decorate(A.new)
decorated.decorated_methods # => [:bar, :hi]
```

Closest to this is ruby's builtin `instance_methods` method but it returns both base object methods and decorator methods (In this example returns `[:foo, :bar, :hi]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/21115) it in to Draper, e.g:

Put this in `config/initializers/draper.rb`:

```
 module DraperExtensions
   def decorated_methods
     instance_methods.to_set - Draper::Decorator.instance_methods.to_set   
   end
 end

 Draper::Decorator.extend DraperExtensions
```

Then you will be able to call:

```
ADecorator.decorated_methods
```

Comment: It kinda works, it returns the 'decorated methods' and also `method_missing` but this is not difficult to exclude. Is there a way to do something like this without using an initializer? Let's say create a regular instance method in the decorator or maybe put it in a mixin or a base class which is then inherited by the decorator?

Comment: end up making a method inside the class instead of monkey patching removing method missing from the list!

Comment: I suspect the `method_missing` occurs as a result of Draper's [`delegate`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#delegating-methods) functionality.

Comment: FYI there's more explanation of the monkey patching approach I used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i/4471202#4471202).

Comment: nice question out there in the link!