# How to call active record's association method if we have same method name in current model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Using Ruby and Rails, I did following code

```
class Department
end
class Employee
  field :depaertment_id, :default => nil
  belongs_to :department, :autosave => false
  def department
    dept = self.super.department # check whether associated department object exists as per self.department active record's method
    if dept.nil?
      #other operation
    end
  end
end
```

Here from `department method` I need get `department object`

If I do following code then department object is easily available as per rails association

```
class Employee
 field :depaertment_id, :default => nil
 belongs_to :department, :autosave => false
 def get_department
   dept = self.department 
   if dept.nil?
     #other operation
   end
 end
end
```

How can I get department object?

Comment: `self.associations["department"]
#<Mongoid::Relations::Metadata
  autobuild:    false
  class_name:   Department
  cyclic:       nil
  dependent:    nil
  inverse_of:   nil
  key:          department_id
  macro:        belongs_to
  name:         department
  order:        nil
  polymorphic:  false
  relation:     Mongoid::Relations::Referenced::In
  setter:       department=
  versioned:    false>`

Comment: perhaps add a mongoid tag in there to help you get better scoped answers for what you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Method Wrapping from [Monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

```
class Department
end
class Employee
  field :depaertment_id, :default => nil
  belongs_to :department, :autosave => false
  old_dept = instance_method(:department)
  define_method(:department) do
  dept = old_bar.bind(self).()
  if dept.nil?
      #other code...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the association method and then load the target of the association, for example:

```
def department
    dept = self.association(:department).load_target
    if dept.nil?
        #other operation
    end
end
```

this will load the related association instead of recursively calling your department method

Comment: *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `association' for #<Employee:0x007fe9a2cd1ca0>

Comment: what version of ruby and what version of rails are you using?

Comment: `Rails 3.1.3` and `Ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]`

Comment: ahh, right, my bad, i just realised your Employee class isnt deriving from ActiveRecord, so the syntax or method may be different

Comment: `load_target` worked for me. The problem as that returns an array instead of an ActiveRecord collection, so it can't be chained with a `where` or any other.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested in console, but in theory, I think `super` should be enough:

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :department, :autosave => false

  def department
    # super will load the department association

    if super.nil?
      # Do your override here.
    else
      # to return the default
      super
    end
  end
end
```

`super` will try to find #department method in the superclass of the Parent class

More info here: https://medium.com/rubycademy/the-super-keyword-a75b67f46f05

Comment: This should  also works in has_many association, eg `super.where(condition)`