# Can I add a custom method to an existing Ruby class?

Tags: ruby, methods

I was given an exercise, in which I was supposed to implement like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].custom_method(arg)
```

I have no idea how this would be done or if it can be done.

Comment: You probably need to read a book to accomplish a task.

Comment: [Refinemenets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) would do.

Comment: I'm aware I can have a custom instance method. I'm wondering if I can have a custom method like above on an instance of Array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i)

Answer (score 4):

To add a method to all array objects, you need override them, like this:

```
class Array
  def custom_method(multiplier)
    self.map{ |e| e*args }
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].custom_method(2)
```

Now, we need more information about what you want to do.

Comment: What my custom method does is moot right now. For arguments sake, let's say it needs to return all even numbers. Again, I don't need help with that though. So, you're saying the only way accomplish this is to add a method to the Array class?

Comment: Yes my friend  @ss_matches :|

Comment: Me either. True, this isn't best practice, but it works.

Comment: Exactly @the_storyteller!

Comment: how can I overide an Array class in my Ruby On Rails project?

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign the new method only to the instance itself using `instance_eval`.
You can try doing something like this:

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4]

my_array.instance_eval do
  def custom_method(args) do
    # do whatever you need to here
  end
end

my_array.custom_method(args) # you would invoke this with your arguments
                             # whatever they may be
```

[Source](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want a singleton method on an object. But I don't think it makes any sense to do that unless that object can be referred to in at least two different occasions: when the method is defined, and when the method is called. So, in order to let it make sense, you at least have to assign that object to a variable or something. Then, there are some ways to define a singleton method on it.

One way is defining directly on it:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

def a.foo
  "foo"
end

a.foo # => "foo"
[1, 2, 3].foo # >> NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
```

Another way is to define it as an instance method of its singleton class.

```
b = [1,2,3,4]

class << b
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end

b.foo #=> "foo"
[1, 2, 3].foo # >> NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
```

Comment: While this isn't wrong, it's probably better to do it by defining a `module`, then extending the instance with that module. This is how ActiveRecord works some of its dark wizardry internally.