# Can I call a custom method on an object with this notation?

Tags: ruby

This is an example of what I am after:

```
def already_taken?
  # Magic goes here...
end

"Charlotte".already_taken?
```

Would it be possible to construct a method in a way where I can call it directly on a String object, without having to modify the String class itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add methods to any class (`String` in this case), without monkey-patching it, you should consider using [Refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

```
module StringRefinements 
  refine String do
    def already_taken?
      puts "yes!"
    end
  end
end

# in another file...
using StringRefinements
"Charlotte".already_taken?
```

The `already_taken?` method will only be available in a scope that calls `using StringRefinements` and nowhere else.

Comment: Thank you, Danny! This is exactly what I was after. Also, one more question: Is this considered a bad implementation compared to just modifying the String class?

Comment: @MihkelPajunen in general, you should avoid modifying Ruby's build-in classes.

Comment: Both Refinements and monkey patching have their place. Refinements is a good practice especially when you know you want the method "locally". Monkey patching (i.e. opening the `String` class) is NOT considered bad practice if used with caution. For example, in your own projects, if you need a globally available method. But if it is something local, or if you develop a gem for public consumption - I would consider if monkey patching is needed. And I disagree with @Stefan's comment above - Ruby has open classes for this exact reason and many widely used projects monkey patch everything.

Answer (score 2):

You could patch the String class with a custom module:

```
module MyStringPatch

  def already_taken?
    'yes'
  end

end

String.include MyStringPatch

"Charlotte".already_taken?
```

Comment: Why is this better than just adding the method to the string class directly?

Comment: `"Charlotte".extend(MyStringPatch).already_taken?` would add the methods to that instance only, leaving the `String` class unchanged.

Comment: Sure, but why is including the module better than just adding the already_taken? method directly into the string class? Class String def already_taken? end end

Comment: @Mark, this is just my opinion: is cleaner, DRYer, useful for mixin and prevent to override default methods, where both opening the class or `String.prepend MyStringPatch` do. Here an interesting post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i

Comment: One reason this is better is that if someone is looking at your code and wondering where this method comes from, they can do something like `'Charlotte'.method(:already_taken?).owner #=> MyStringPatch`, and it is very clear where the method comes from. Even better if the name of the module were more self-explanatory than just `MyStringPatch`.