# monkey patching the * operator

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, monkeypatching

im new to ruby and trying to understand monkey patching.

so while practicing on an old project which is a simple Vektor calculator.

I wrote the following code which will allow me to multiply a Vektor with a number and two vectors with each other:

```
  class Vektor 
    attr_accessor :x #instead of getter and setter!-

    def initialize (*vektors)
      if vektors.length==0
        @x=Array.new(3,0)
      else
        @x=vektors
      end
    end

    def size
      @x.length
    end


    def *(other)
      case other
      when Vektor
        if (self.size != other.size)
          return "the vektors don't have the same length!"
        else
          result=0
          for i in 0 ... other.size
            result += (self.x[i] * other.x[i])
          end
          return result
        end
      when Numeric
        for i in 0 ... self.size
          self.x[i]*=other
        end
        return self
      end
    end
  end
```

and here is the integer class so i would be able to do the multiplication in an other way per example like this -> `5*vektor`

```
  class Integer
    def mul(other)
      for i in 0 ... other.size
        other.x[i]*=self # this is the cause of the error!
      end
      return other
    end
    alias_method :* , :mul
  end

  obj1=Vektor.new(2,2,2)
  puts 3*obj1
```

my problem is that I'm getting a raised error and I don't know why but I could assume it is because I'm using the `*` in the `alias_method` while it is being been used inside the `mul` method.

the output is the following :

```
undefined method `x' for 3:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

## Edited:

### the assignment text:

> Extend the Integer class with a monkey patch so that you can write 5 *
>   vector instead of vector * 5.
>
> Test whether this patch works via a suitable unit test.
>
> Tip: You will want to use the alias keyword or the alias_method method
>   to achieve the goal.

I totally understand the cause of the problem but I can't seem to find a workaround where I could prevent the error from occurring!.

this is what I'm currently at, which is working but in a Wrong way :(

```
class Integer
  def mul(other)
    case (other)
    when Numeric
      return self*other
    when Vektor
      for i in 0 ... other.size
        other.x[i]*=self # this is the cause of the error!
      end
      return other
    end
  end
  alias_method :**,:mul
end

obj1=Vektor.new(2,2,2)

puts obj1*3
puts 3**Vektor.new(3,3,3)
```

please note that all that I care about at this point is to know to extend my knowledge and not to get one silly note. :)

Comment: In the `when Numeric` block, you call `self.x[i]*=other`. If my understanding is correct, `self.x[i]` is a number so this ends up calling `<number>.mul(<number>)`. So I think you need to do a typecheck in the `mul` method to see whether `other` is a `Numeric` or `Vektor`. Although I haven't fully followed your logic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```rb
> other.x[i]*=self
> ```

is the same as

```rb
other.x[i] = other.x[i] * self
```

or to make it really explicit

```rb
other.x().[]=(i)(other.x().[](i).*(self))
```

`other.x[i]` is an `Integer`, and `self` is also an `Integer` (in this case `3`).
In your `Integer` method, you call `other.x`, but when you multiply `some_integer * 3`, then in your `Integer#*` method, `other` is `3`, so you are calling `3.x` which indeed doesn't exist.

Note that your `Vektor#*` method is now also broken, because it, too, needs to multiply two `Integer`s, but you just overwrote the `Integer#*` method which knows how to multiply two `Integer`s (and actually also knows how to multiply an `Integer` with *any object* that correctly implements the [`Numeric#coerce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce) protocol) with one that only knows how to multiply an `Integer` and a `Vektor`, and thus no longer knows how to multiply two `Integer`s.

Another problem is that in your `Vektor#*` method, you check for `other` being an instance of `Numeric`, but then the other way around you only implement multiplication for `Integer`s. This makes your multiplication asymmetric, e.g. `some_vektor * 1.0` will work, but `1.0 * some_vektor` won't.

The correct implementation would be to not touch `Integer` *at all*, and simply implement the numeric coercion protocol. That will solve all of your problems: you don't have to monkey-patch *anything*, and your `Vektor`s will automatically work with *any* `Numeric` in the core library, the standard library, the Ruby ecosystem and in fact even with ones that haven't even been written yet. Something like this:

```rb
class Vektor
  def self.inherited(*)
    raise TypeError, "#{self} is immutable and cannot be inherited from."
  end

  def initialize(*vektors)
    self.x = if vektors.size.zero?
      Array.new(3, 0)
    else
      vektors
    end.freeze
  end

  singleton_class.alias_method :[], :new

  alias_method :length, def size
    x.size
  end

  def coerce(other)
    [self, other]
  end

  def *(other)
    case other
    when Vektor
      raise ArgumentError, "the vektors don't have the same length!" if size != other.size
      x.zip(other.x).map {|a, b| a * b }.sum
    when Numeric
      self.class.new(*x.map(&other.method(:*)))
    else
      a, b = other.coerce(self)
      a * b
    end
  end

  protected

  attr_reader :x # `x` should not be writeable by anybody!

  private

  attr_writer :x

  freeze
end
```

You will notice that I made some changes to your code:

- `Vektor`s are now immutable and `Vektor#*` returns a new `Vektor` instead of mutating `self`. It is generally a good idea to keep your objects immutable as far as possible, but it is *especially* important (and expected, really) for "number-like" objects such as `Vektor`s. You would be terribly surprised if `2 * 3` didn't return `6` but rather made `2` have the value `6`, wouldn't you? But that is exactly what your code was doing with `Vektor`s!
- `x` is no longer exposed to everybody, and most importantly, no longer *writeable* by everybody.
- I replaced all of your loops with higher-level iteration constructs. As a general rule, if you are writing a loop in Ruby, you are doing something wrong. There are so many powerful methods in [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) that you should never need a loop.

I also wrote some tests to demonstrate that without even touching *any* class outside of `Vektor`, we now support multiplication of `int * vek`, `vek * int`, `float * vek`, `vek * float`, `rational * vek`, `vek * rational`, `complex * vek`, and `vek * complex`, simply by implementing the `Numeric#coerce` coercion protocol.

```rb
require 'test/unit'
class VektorTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_creating_an_empty_vektor_actually_creates_a_zero_vektor_of_dimension_3
    v = Vektor.new
    assert_equal 3, v.size
  end

  def test_that_square_brackets_is_an_alias_for_new
    v = Vektor[]
    assert_equal 3, v.size
  end


  def test_that_we_can_multiply_two_trivial_vektors
    v1 = Vektor[2]
    v2 = Vektor[3]
    assert_equal 6, v1 * v2
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_two_nontrivial_vektors
    v1 = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    v2 = Vektor[5, 6, 7]
    assert_equal 56, v1 * v2
  end


  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_trivial_vektor_with_an_integer
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6], v * 3 # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_trivial_vektor_with_an_integer_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3 }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_an_integer
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6, 9, 12], v * 3 # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_an_integer_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3 }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_an_integer_with_a_trivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6], 3 * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_an_integer_with_a_trivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3 * v }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_an_integer_with_a_nontrivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6, 9, 12], 3 * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_an_integer_with_a_nontrivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3 * v }
  end


  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_trivial_vektor_with_a_float
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6.0], v * 3.0 # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_trivial_vektor_with_a_float_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3.0 }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_a_float
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6.0, 9.0, 12.0], v * 3.0 # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_an_float_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3.0 }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_float_with_a_trivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6.0], 3.0 * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_float_with_a_trivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3.0 * v }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_float_with_a_nontrivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6.0, 9.0, 12.0], 3.0 * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_float_with_a_nontrivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3.0 * v }
  end


  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_trivial_vektor_with_a_rational
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6r], v * 3r # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_trivial_vektor_with_a_rational_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3r }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_a_rational
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6r, 9r, 12r], v * 3r # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_an_rational_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3r }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_rational_with_a_trivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6r], 3r * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_rational_with_a_trivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3r * v }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_rational_with_a_nontrivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6r, 9r, 12r], 3r * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_rational_with_a_nontrivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3r * v }
  end


  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_trivial_vektor_with_a_complex_number
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6i], v * 3i # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_trivial_vektor_with_a_complex_number_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3i }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_a_complex_number
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6i, 9i, 12i], v * 3i # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_nontrivial_vektor_with_an_complex_number_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { v * 3i }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_complex_number_with_a_trivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_equal Vektor[6i], 3i * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_complex_number_with_a_trivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3i * v }
  end

  def test_that_we_can_multiply_a_complex_number_with_a_nontrivial_vektor
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_equal Vektor[6i, 9i, 12i], 3i * v # this will fail because you haven't implemented equality!
  end

  def test_that_multiplying_a_complex_number_with_a_nontrivial_vektor_at_least_does_not_raise_an_exception
    v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]
    assert_nothing_raised { 3i * v }
  end
end
```

Let's also add some methods that you generally always need to implement to make your objects work with the rest of the Ruby ecosystem:

```rb
class Vektor
  def ==(other)
    x == other.x
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.is_a?(Vektor) && self == other
  end

  def hash
    x.hash
  end

  def to_s
    "(#{x.join(', ')})"
  end

  def inspect
    "Vektor#{x.inspect}"
  end
end
```

If you absolutely *must* use monkey-patching, then it is important that you *retain access* to the old version of the method that you are monkey-patching. The tool to do this is the [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) method. It would look something like this:

```rb
class Vektor
  def self.inherited(*)
    raise TypeError, "#{self} is immutable and cannot be inherited from."
  end

  attr_reader :x # `x` should not be writeable by anybody!

  def initialize(*vektors)
    self.x = if vektors.size.zero?
      Array.new(3, 0)
    else
      vektors
    end.freeze
  end

  singleton_class.alias_method :[], :new

  alias_method :length, def size
    x.size
  end

  def *(other)
    case other
    when Vektor
      raise ArgumentError, "the vektors don't have the same length!" if size != other.size
      x.zip(other.x).map {|a, b| a * b }.sum
    when Numeric
      self.class.new(*x.map(&other.method(:*)))
    end
  end

  private

  attr_writer :x

  freeze
end
```

(Mostly identical, but without the `coerce` method and without the `else` clause in the `case` expression, and the `x` reader needs to be `public`.)

```rb
module IntegerTimesVektorExtension
  def *(other)
    return Vektor[*other.x.map(&method(:*))] if other.is_a?(Vektor)
    super
  end
end
```

And because monkey-patching core classes is really dangerous, we use a *refinement*, to make sure that the monkey-patch is only active where you *explicitly* activate the refinement with `using IntegerTimesVektorRefinement`.

```rb
module IntegerTimesVektorRefinement
  refine Integer do
    prepend IntegerTimesVektorExtension
  end
end
```

Now, we can do something like this:

```rb
v = Vektor[2, 3, 4]

5 * v
# `*': Vektor can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)

using IntegerTimesVektorRefinement

5 * v
#=> <#<Vektor:0x00007fcc88868588 @x=[10, 15, 20]>
```

[In the dark old times, before `Module#prepend` existed, we had to resort to other dirty tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988) to be able to keep the monkey-patched method around. However, as of the release of Ruby 2.0 on February, 24th 2013, which includes `Module#prepend`, these tricks are no longer necessary, and *should not be used, nor taught*. This includes the `alias_method` chain trick, which looks like this:

```rb
class Integer
  alias_method :original_mul, :*

  def *(other)
    return Vektor[*other.x.map(&method(:*))] if other.is_a?(Vektor)
    original_mul(other)
  end
end
```

But, as mentioned: you *should not do this*.

The best solution is to implement the `coerce` protocol. Really not "just" the best solution but the *only correct* solution.

If, for some reason, you *do not want* to implement the `coerce` protocol, then the best solution is `Module#prepend`. Ideally with refinement, but please be aware that not all Ruby implementations implement refinements.

If you really, really, really, must do monkey-patching, and are using a ten-year old, unsupported, unmaintained, obsolete, outdated version of Ruby and thus cannot use `Module#prepend`, then there are *still* [better solutions out there than `alias_method`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988), such as grabbing the instance method as a `Method` object and storing it in a local variable that you close over.

Using `alias_method` here is not necessary, if not outright *wrong*, and bad, outdated, obsolete practice.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time and the effort for writing all that but first i want to tell that sadly enough I have to make it in using monkey patch because it is an assignment. plus in the `Vektor*` i had to check if the other is numeric so I can perform multiplication with skalar and skalar multiplication between two vektors!. but you explained the source of the error very well but also checking if other is numeric in the `Integer*` then returning `self*other` raises a `stack too deep error`

Comment: If you monkey-patch the `Integer#*` method, then the original method, which knows how to multiply two integers *does no longer exist*. Since, however, you *need* this method inside both the `Integer#*` and `Vektor#*` methods, the assignment you have been given is impossible. The correct solution is to use Ruby's arithmetic coercion protocol, which allows all the other classes to *automatically* work with `Vektor` without you having to do anything. (It's not quite true that it is *impossible*, but it is much more complex. Certainly above a beginner course, I would say.)

Comment: please take a look at the post again i added the assignment text (translated from german) and added where im currently at!.