# Executing code for every method call in a Ruby module

Tags: ruby, methods, module, metaprogramming

I'm writing a module in Ruby 1.9.2 that defines several methods. When any of these methods is called, I want each of them to execute a certain statement first.

```
module MyModule
  def go_forth
    a re-used statement
    # code particular to this method follows ...
  end

  def and_multiply
    a re-used statement
    # then something completely different ...
  end
end
```

But I want to avoid putting that `a re-used statement` code explicitly in every single method. Is there a way to do so?

(If it matters, `a re-used statement` will have each method, when called, print its own name. It will do so via some variant of `puts __method__`.)

Comment: The question relates to Ruby 1.9.2. But these days, if you just found this question, you're probably using Ruby 2+. In Ruby 2+ `prepend` is a good option. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219277/how-do-i-wrap-the-invocation-of-a-ruby-method-by-including-a-module

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Like this:

```
module M
  def self.before(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      m = instance_method(name)
      define_method(name) do |*args, &block|  
        yield
        m.bind(self).(*args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end

module M
  def hello
    puts "yo"
  end

  def bye
    puts "bum"
  end

  before(*instance_methods) { puts "start" }
end

class C
  include M
end

C.new.bye #=> "start" "bum"
C.new.hello #=> "start" "yo"
```

Comment: +1 Like it. But Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't support it? `NoMethodError: undefined method `before' for M:Module`

Comment: @fl00r, all you should have to change to have it work in 1.8.7 is the proc invocation syntax, i'm using `.()` (which is 1.9 only) rather than `.call()`

Comment: Hi, could you explain me what exactly m.bind(self).(*args, &block) do? I've search the ruby documentation and many pages from google, but I still don't know how it works. Many thx for help.

Comment: @reizals See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind. (Reply is just for everyone's reference.)

Comment: So, the location of the bind is important? We can't make it at the beggining of the class definition?

Comment: Dude, this is beautiful.  Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @horseyguy Wait, are we defining an overriding method? So `before` needs to be defined after the original method?

Comment: I didn't even know about .(), nice.

Comment: Wait, why doesn't this work if you use the before method in the C class definition?  if you move `before(*instance_methods) { puts "start " }` to C class I get `<class:C>': undefined method `before' for C:Class (NoMethodError)`

Comment: How to pass arguments onto it?

Answer (score 12):

This is exactly what **[aspector](http://github.com/gcao/aspector)** is created for.

With aspector you don't need to write the boilerplate metaprogramming code. You can even go one step further to extract the common logic into a separate aspect class and test it independently.

```
require 'aspector'

module MyModule
  aspector do
    before :go_forth, :add_multiply do
      ...
    end
  end

  def go_forth
    # code particular to this method follows ...
  end

  def and_multiply
    # then something completely different ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement it with `method_missing` through proxy Module, like this:

```
module MyModule

  module MyRealModule
    def self.go_forth
      puts "it works!"
      # code particular to this method follows ...
    end

    def self.and_multiply
      puts "it works!"
      # then something completely different ...
    end
  end

  def self.method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    reused_statement
    if MyModule::MyRealModule.methods.include?( m.to_s )
      MyModule::MyRealModule.send(m)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.reused_statement
    puts "reused statement"
  end
end

MyModule.go_forth
#=> it works!
MyModule.stop_forth
#=> NoMethodError...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by metaprogramming technique, here's an example:

```
module YourModule
  def included(mod)
    def mod.method_added(name)
      return if @added 
      @added = true
      original_method = "original #{name}"
      alias_method original_method, name
      define_method(name) do |*args|
        reused_statement
        result = send original_method, *args
        puts "The method #{name} called!"
        result
      end
      @added = false
    end
  end

  def reused_statement
  end
end

module MyModule
  include YourModule

  def go_forth
  end

  def and_multiply
  end
end
```

works only in ruby 1.9 and higher

UPDATE: and also can't use block, i.e. no yield in instance methods

Answer (score 3):

I dunno, why I was downvoted - but a proper AOP framework is better than meta-programming hackery. And thats what OP was trying to achieve.

http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2006/06/does-ruby-need-aop.html

Another Solution could be:

```
module Aop
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def before_filter(method_name, options = {})
      aop_methods = Array(options[:only]).compact
      return if aop_methods.empty?
      aop_methods.each do |m|
        alias_method "#{m}_old", m
        class_eval <<-RUBY,__FILE__,__LINE__ + 1
          def #{m}
            #{method_name}
            #{m}_old
          end
        RUBY
      end
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  def hello
    puts "Running hello world"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar
  def find_hello
    puts "Running find hello"
  end
  include Aop
  before_filter :find_hello, :only => :hello
end

a = Foo.new()
a.hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with meta-programming.

Another alternative is [Aquarium](https://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium). Aquarium is a framework that implements Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) for Ruby. AOP allow you to implement functionality across normal object and method boundaries. Your use case, applying a pre-action on every method, is a basic task of AOP.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, either. Perhaps it was because there was no example just a link.

Comment: Downvoting for link to random library without any explanation as to why I should click the link