# Calling a specific method before or after a method is called

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm using ruby 1.9.2-p136

What i want to do is, create two methods: **before_method** and **after_method**

When i do this in a class:

```
before_method :foo, :bar
```

it should run these two methods before any called method, i.e. if i call a class method **foo1**, the order in which the methods should be executed is:
    foo
    bar
    foo1

Also, i want a method **after_method** which does the opposite of **before_method**

Can anyone tell how to go about it??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an Aspect framework for Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing code for every method call in a Ruby module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module) Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137238/how-can-i-intercept-method-call-in-ruby

Comment: Can't you just used `alias_method` to do this trivially? Seems like this is a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do this for ActiveRecord Models? Or just generic classes? Because I've written a rails plugin that adds `before_filter` and `after_filter` methods to the ActiveRecord Models.

Maybe you can use it, or look at the code and go from there: https://github.com/deleteman/Filtered-Models

Hope that helps!

If you have questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Nah, not for rails, just plain Ruby.
Yeah, would take a look at the code, hope it'll show me the path! :)
Thanks mate

Comment: Hopefully it'll give you some idea, if you have some questions, my e-mail is on the readme :)

Comment: Yeah, will surely do that!! Thanks!! :)

Comment: Don't know if you manage to get this working, but I eventually wrote this gem that does something pretty similar to what you were looking for and it only needs ruby to work: https://rubygems.org/gems/Conditionator