# How to intercept class method calls, not just instance method calls

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming

Can someone help me modify the answer provided for [intercepting instance method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137238/how-can-i-intercept-method-call-in-ruby) so that it works with either class method calls, or both class and instance method calls? From my limited knowledge of metaprogramming with Ruby, I'd imagine it would have something to do with opening up the singleton class some place using `class << self`, but I've tried doing that in various places with this code and I can't seem to figure it out. Instead of a direct answer, though, could you provide me with a push in the right direction? I'm a big fan of figuring things out for myself unless I'm completely out of my depth. Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right tack. Try putting your `class << self` code in to the class definition itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution modified from the answer in the link you provided. I moved the hook logic from super class to a separate module so that when ever a class needs the hook, it just include or extend that module and call the hook method.

- `before_each_method type, &block` - `type` can be `:class` or `:instance`, and the block is the code to be executed before each method. The block will be evaluated under certain environments, that is, for instance methods, `self` in the block is the instance; for class methods, `self` in the block is the class.
- `before_class_method &block` - alias for `before_each_method :class, &block`
- `before_instance_method &block` - alias for `before_each_method :instance, &block`

```rb
module MethodHooker
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  def self.extended(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def before_each_method type, &block
      singleton = class << self; self; end
      case type
      when :instance
        this = self
        singleton.instance_eval do
          define_method :method_added do |name|
            last = instance_variable_get(:@__last_methods_added)
            return if last and last.include?(name)
            with = :"#{name}_with_before_each_method"
            without = :"#{name}_without_before_each_method"
            instance_variable_set(:@__last_methods_added, [name, with, without])
            this.class_eval do
              define_method with do |*args, &blk|
                instance_exec(name, args, blk, &block)
                send without, *args, &blk
              end
              alias_method without, name
              alias_method name, with
            end
            instance_variable_set(:@__last_methods_added, nil)
          end
        end
      when :class
        this = self
        singleton.instance_eval do
          define_method :singleton_method_added do |name|
            return if name == :singleton_method_added
            last = instance_variable_get(:@__last_singleton_methods_added)
            return if last and last.include?(name)
            with = :"#{name}_with_before_each_method"
            without = :"#{name}_without_before_each_method"
            instance_variable_set(:@__last_singleton_methods_added, [name, with, without])
            singleton.class_eval do
              define_method with do |*args, &blk|
                instance_exec(name, args, blk, &block)
                send without, *args, &blk
              end
              alias_method without, name
              alias_method name, with
            end
            instance_variable_set(:@__last_singleton_methods_added, nil)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    def before_class_method &block
      before_each_method :class, &block
    end
    def before_instance_method &block
      before_each_method :instance, &block
    end
  end
end

class Test
  extend MethodHooker
  before_each_method :instance do |method, args, block|
    p [method, args, block]
    puts "before instance method(#{method}) #{@var}"
  end
  before_class_method do |method, args, block|
    puts "before class method(#{method}) #{@class_instance_var}"
  end
  @class_instance_var = 'stackoverflow'
  def initialize
    @var = 1
  end
  def test(a, b, c)
    puts "instance method test"
  end
  def self.test1
    puts "class method test"
  end
end

Test.new.test(1, "arg2", [3]) {|t| t}
Test.test1
```

The output will be something like:

```
[:initialize, [], nil]
before instance method(initialize)
[:test, [1, "arg2", [3]], #<Proc:0x00000001017d5eb8@/Users/test/before_method.rb:88>]
before instance method(test) 1
instance method test
before class method(test1) stackoverflow
class method test
```

Comment: This is pretty cool! I'm trying to digest it all before using it though haha. Could you explain to me what this snippet is doing (inside the 'when :instance' block):
`define_method with do |*args, &blk|
  instance_exec(name, args, blk, &block)
  send without, *args, &blk
end`

Comment: specifically the use of `instance_exec()`. I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: I think I got it! This snippet is where the 'rerouting' happens: the call to `instance_exec()` will pass the original arguments (given to the original method call) to the block given to `before_each_method` and then execute that block; afterwards it will send perform the original method call with the proper arguments. Is that about right?

Comment: @DesAdams yes, you're right. `instance_exec` will pass its arguments to its block, so `name, args, blk` will be passed to `block`, and then the block specified in `before_each_method` will be called with `name, args, blk` as arguments.