# call before methods in model on ruby

Tags: ruby, model, metaprogramming

This my implementation to developing way to run code before all method in your model

The call "before_hook :months_used" method need to be on bottom of class to the ExecutionHooks can get the instance_method loaded in the module. I would like to load the instance methods on top

```
class BalanceChart < BalanceFind
 include ExecutionHooks

 attr_reader :options

 def initialize(options = {})
  @options = options
  @begin_at = @options[:begin_at]
 end

 def months_used
  range.map{|date| I18n.l date, format: :month_year}.uniq!
 end

 before_hook :months_used
end

module ExecutionHooks

def self.included(base)
 base.send :extend, ClassMethods
end

module ClassMethods
  def before
   @hooks.each do |name|
    m = instance_method(name)
    define_method(name) do |*args, &block|  

      return if @begin_at.blank? ## the code you can execute before methods

      m.bind(self).(*args, &block) ## your old code in the method of the class
    end
   end
  end

  def before_hook(*method_name)
   @hooks = method_name
   before
  end

  def hooks
   @hooks ||= []
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: You mean you would like to call before_hook at the top of your class?

Comment: Yes @FrederickCheung

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend). `prepend` is like `include` in that it adds a module to the ancestors of the class, however instead of adding it after the class it adds it before.

This means that if a method exists both in the prepended module and the class then the module implementation is called first (and it can optionally call `super` if it wants to call the base class).

This allows you to write a hooks module like so:

```
module Hooks
  def before(*method_names)
    to_prepend = Module.new do
      method_names.each do |name| 
        define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
          puts "before #{name}"
          super(*args,&block)
        end
      end
    end
    prepend to_prepend
  end
end


class Example
  extend Hooks
  before :foo, :bar

  def foo
    puts "in foo"
  end
  def bar
    puts "in bar"
  end
end
```

In real use you would probably want to stash that module somewhere so that each call to `before` doesn't create a new module but that is just an inplementation detail

Comment: thanks. I'll try testing your code latter and repply a feedback

Comment: Umm.. Doesn't seem to be working for me. Tried in `irb` (Ruby-2.0.0-p247). Calling `Example.new.foo` printed only `before foo` `in foo`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Found your implementation and seems nice, however can you expand a bit on the last comment. As far as I understand you'll only load the `Example` class once, and at that point the `before` method will be called creating only one module for the `Example` class. Hope I explained properly

Comment: That’s correct. If you call Example.new.foo, what else would you expect as output other than “before foo in foo”?

Answer (score 2):

@rathrio This is my implementation using method_added that you talked. Thanks

```js
module ExecutionHooks

  def validation
    p "works1"
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end
end

module ClassMethods
  attr_writer :hooked
  
  def hooked
    @hooked ||= []
  end

  def method_added(method)
    return if @hooks.nil? 
    return unless @hooks.include?(method)
    m = self.instance_method(method)
    unless hooked.include?(method)
      hooked << method
      define_method(method) do |*args, &block|  
        validation      
        m.bind(self).(*args, &block) ## your old code in the method of the class
      end
    end
  end

  def before_hook(*method_name)
    @hooks = method_name
  end

  def hooks
    @hooks ||= []
  end
 end
end

class BalanceChart < BalanceFind
 include ExecutionHooks
 before_hook :months_data, :months_used, :debits_amount, :test

  def test
    "test"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redefining the method when calling `before_hook`, you could override the [`method_added`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-method_added) hook to prepend your before hooks to a method right after it was defined. This way your `before_hook` calls can be (actually, must be) placed at the top of the class definition.