# Using Pundit for all-access "super_admin" role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I'm wondering the best/simplest way to give a user "super_admin" access using the Pundit gem -- or, what's the simplest way to give a user access to all controller actions across the site?

I realize I can edit the policy file for each controller, then add something like

```
def delete?
  user.is_super_admin?
end
```

...to each and every action, in each and every controller. But is there a single place where I could define this?

I've taken a look at the application policy, which all of my other controller policies inherit from, but I believe these actions are all overridden in my controllers anyway so I don't think I could define it there.

I'm sure others have needed to implement this feature? What's the simplest way? Thanks!

Comment: maybe i should use pure ruby and add something like this to my application_policy.rb, which could check if user.is_super_admin? for all actions defined in the class?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5515144/580419

Comment: cancancan gem allows this, I don't know why pundit doesn't have something built in. https://github.com/varvet/pundit/issues/191

Answer (score 2):

For the (in reality) minimal annoyance that comes from retyping a method name a couple dozen times through the life of the project, I think the maybe not-so-obvious benefit is worth it.

First, you could save a few keystrokes by defining a `super?` method on your `ApplicationPolicy`

```
def super?
  user.is_super_admin?
end
```

And then your `delete?` and other methods could be simplified just a bit.

```
def delete?
  super? || user.id == record.user_id # super admin or owner of the resource
end
```

Pundit policies are simple enough. If I have never worked in your code before, I can look at the above method and know exactly who can perform the deletion.

Sure, it might save you a couple keystrokes to have some meta-programmed functionality to call `super?` automagically, with `delete?` appearing as

```
def delete?
  user.id == record.user_id # super admin or owner of the resource
end
```

but now the clarity is lost. Also, what if there is a method down the road you **do not** want the super admin to have access to? Reworking your already more complicated solution would make things even more prone to bugs and more difficult to understand. All so ~10 keystrokes per method could be saved.

---

#### Update

Opinions on code readability aside, here is one implementation that does what you seem to be after. You might also look into [hooking the method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137238/how-can-i-intercept-method-call-in-ruby) instead of removing the `?` from the method names as I've done below to make sure `method_missing` picks them up.

```
#
# Classes
#

User = Struct.new(:id, :name)
Foo  = Struct.new(:id, :title, :user_id)

class SuperUser < User; end

ApplicationPolicy = Struct.new(:user, :record) do

  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user   = user
    @record = record
  end

  def method_missing(name)
    raise NoMethodError, "No method `#{name}` for #{self}" if (name =~ /\?$/).nil?

    user.is_a?(SuperUser) || send(name.to_s.sub(/\?$/, ""))
  end

end

class FooPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  private

    def edit
      user.id == record.user_id
    end

end


#
# Fixtures
#

user = User.new(1, "Deefour")
foo  = Foo.new(1, "A Sample Foo", 1)

super_user = SuperUser.new(2, "FireDragon")


#
# Examples
#

FooPolicy.new(user, foo).edit?       #=> true
FooPolicy.new(super_user, foo).edit? #=> true
```

Comment: appreciate the tip to define a reusable method in the application policy, but in general i disagree that you would lose clarity or practice poor coding by not putting 'super? || ' in every method, in every Pundit class. Pundit class structures mirror the structure of ActionController::Base -- and this already has helper methods like before_action/after_action. I'm sure as a Rails programmer you probably use before_action a lot and wouldn't say this is confusing or bad programming to do so. So I think the best solution would actually be to mirror these helpers using Ruby-looking into it now :-)

Comment: in my original question though i was thinking of trying to implement in a single place though, but would agree this is going too far. but writing your own 'before_action' equivalent to use once at the top of each class would be the best solution i feel...keeping things clear, allowing you to not use it for actions if you didn't need it on, and freeing you from repeating the same code a hundred times across many files...

Comment: +0.5 +0.5 for the first part of your answer!