# How to wrap methods with before and after in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-1.9.3

Is there a better way to achieve the following? It seems a little clunky to list the methods as symbols...

This code runs an `init` before and `draw` after for each of the 4 methods. The following code works, but is there a more readable or idiomatic way of doing it?

```
Class DrawMap
  def draw_method_1
    ...
  end

  def draw_method_2
    ...
  end

  def draw_all
    [:draw_method_1, :draw_method_2, :draw_method_3, :draw_method_4].each do |method|
      init_draw
      send method
      @draw.draw
    end
  end

...
```

The Rails before and after filters would do the same thing, but this is not a Rails app.

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: You could look at the before/after code of Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to make the code above a *little* cleaner, you could try this:

```
def draw_all
  (1..4).each do |n|
    init_draw
    send "draw_method_#{n}"
    @draw.draw 
  end
end
```

Otherwise, there is a pretty good SO question [**right here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module) that would really help you out. It involves a little metaprogramming that basically redefines methods and wraps them with some additional code. In your case, you would wrap with `init_draw` and `draw`.

Comment: Yes, that SO question is very relevant.