# Rails call back before every calling a method before every static method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I need to call a method before every static method called in rails.

is it possible

Example:

```
Class A

 #Here a bunch of statements before every static method

 def self.b
  # some code related to b
 end

  def self.a
  # some code related to a
 end
end
```

when I call A.b then the output should be:

==========

bunch of statements before every static method and

code related to b

==========

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just have look at the answer of this question, May you get some hint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module

Comment: Thanks, but I am using ruby 1.8.7 and I didn't found the exact solution I want there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
class A

 def self.hello
   print "how are"

 end

 def self.before_stuff
  print "you"
 end

 begin
  print "hello,"
 end
end

 A.hello
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (though I'd first consider what you're trying to do and if there is a better way), here's how I'd approach. I wouldn't try to quietly hook into static method calls. Be explicit:

```
def self.debug_call_static(name)
  # run/call bunch of statements
  self.send(name) if self.respond_to?(name)
end
```

Usage: `A.debug_call_static('b')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are up to, but `yield` is mostly used to solve this kind of problem

```
==========

bunch of statements before every static method and

code related to b

==========
```

What you can do is

```
class A

 def self.exec
   p "Here a bunch of statements before every static method"
   yield
 end

 def self.b
  A.exec do
   p " some code related to b"
  end
 end

  def self.a
   A.exec do
    p " some code related to a "
   end
 end

end
```

**Output**

```
1.9.3p448 :043 > A.b
"Here a bunch of statements before every static method"
" some code related to b"
 => " some code related to b" 
1.9.3p448 :044 >
```

Comment: It is a nice solution, but the only problem for me here is there are lot of static methods in my class and its super class I can overwrite each and every method

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `self.extended` callback on a module and override your class methods

```
class A
  def self.before_stuff
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def a
    end

    def b
    end

    def self.extended(base)
      self.instance_methods.each do |name|
        base.instance_eval do
          alias "handle_#{name}" name
          define_method name do |*args, &block|
            before_stuff
            __send__ "handle_#{name}", *args, &block
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  extend ClassMethods
end
```

Comment: not only for single method b I want to execute these blocks before every static method....i.e. even for a in the example. and also before the static methods of super class

Comment: Nice solution but I don't want to change my method name from a to handle_a

Comment: how about this new version? that uses the `self.extended` callback :)

Comment: very nice solution, But I cant even change that self.a to a. Even I cant change the method definition of a.