# Ruby Squeel library deprecation of core extensions

Tags: ruby, activerecord, replace, squeel

I started maintaining a big app with tons of Squeel queries.
The latest Squeel version (>1.1) is deprecating code extensions:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Core extensions are deprecated and will be
>   removed in Squeel 2.0.

Is there an easy way to grep for the this deprecated symbol and hash core extensions?

Comment: For a moment, I was reading "Ruby squeals library deprecation of core extensions"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) to find the usage of deprecated methods.

Installed it with:

```
$ gem install rubocop
```

and then in your project root run

```
$ rubocop
```

**EDIT:**

You could actually use the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515144/1006863 to print a message every time a method is used.

Other option would be to redefine every method by add the deprecation or fork the project and add it yourself and then ask for a merge request. If it's denied you can keep using your version by specifying the repository in your Gemfile.

Comment: mm, we are using Rubocop but I think that will not work because the deprecation is in the configuration of the extensions, not on every method. [See this](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/commit/df12f2e36d56b1faa73f1ef275712f481b23be0c)