# How to call private method just before another method completes execution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have two methods in rails

```
def foo
    puts "foo"
    find_article
end

def bar
    puts "bar"
    find_article
end

private
def find_article
    do_something
end
```

Is there a way to call find_article without specifying in `foo` and `bar` ?

Comment: Are the public methods controller methods?

Comment: @sawa fair point. I didn't notice 'rails' specified.

Comment: `before_action` or `after_action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in the lines of:

```
module Magic
  def after_method(original, callback)
    all = [*original]
    all.each do |original|
      m = instance_method(original)
      define_method(original) do |*args, &block|
        m.bind(self).(*args, &block)
        send(callback)
      end
    end
  end
end


class X
  extend Magic
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end

  private
  def find_article
    puts "DONE"
  end

  after_method [:foo, :bar], :find_article    
end
X.new.foo
# foo
# done
```

Got little help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515144/1376448)

Answer (score 2):

Rails includes a way to do this with `ActiveModel::Callbacks`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html

```
class FooBar
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  define_model_callbacks :foobar
  after_foobar :find_article

  def foo
    run_callbacks :foobar do
      puts "foo"
    end
  end

  def bar
    run_callbacks :foobar do
      puts "bar"
    end
  end

  private

  def find_article
    puts 'finding article'
  end
end
```

result:

```
[1] pry(main)> FooBar.new.foo
foo
finding article
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> FooBar.new.bar
bar
finding article
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Rails then `after_action`:

```
class MyController
  after_action :find_article

  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end

  private

  def find_article
    do_something
  end
end
```

Comment: If I replace `do_something` with `render template`, it will try to call render function two times, which is invalid.

Comment: It shouldn't, try just putting `find_article` after the `puts` without using `before_action` and see if the same happens.

Comment: Right kris, it works if I put `find_article` after `puts`, but I have to do same thing for 3 different controllers and each controller have 3-4 methods in them.

Comment: I meant to try it to see if it calls render twice, because using `after_action` is effectively the same thing.