# Ruby: LocalJumpError

Tags: ruby

Why am I getting an error:

#### ERROR:

```
LocalJumpError
# ~> no block given (yield)
```

#### CODE:

```
module M
  def hello(text = 'bba')
    puts "yo-#{text}"      # => nil
  end                      # => :hello

  instance_methods  # => [:hello]

  m = instance_method(:hello)  # => #<UnboundMethod: M#hello>

  define_method(:bye) do |*args, &block|  
    yield                                 # ~> LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
    m.bind(self).(*args, &block)
  end                                     # => :bye

end  # => :bye

class A
  include M  # => A
end          # => A


A.new.hello('vv')       # => nil
A.new.bye('zz') do |p|  # => #<A:0x00007fa8c401e090>
  puts "ggg"
end

# >> yo-vv

# ~> LocalJumpError
# ~> no block given (yield)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the difference in the semantics of `def` and `define_method`. See this:

```
module M
  def outer(&block)
    puts "outer: #{yield}"

    def inner1
      puts "inner1: #{yield}"
    end

    M.define_method(:inner2) do
      puts "inner2: #{yield}"
    end

    M.define_method(:inner3) do |&block|
      puts "inner3: #{block.call}"
    end

    inner1 { 1 }
    inner2 { 2 }
    inner3 { 3 }
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

A.new.outer { 0 }
# => outer: 0
#    inner1: 1
#    inner2: 0 (!!!)
#    inner3: 3
```

`yield` only works inside `def`.

Thus, `inner1` calls its own block; but `inner2` uses the block of the `def` it is in. The correct way to invoke the block inside `define_method` is to capture it in the parameter list (as you did), and then use `#call` or `#[]` on it, like `inner3` demonstrates.

In your code, there is no `def` around, thus no block is available when you `yield`. You can use the above method, and replace `yield` with `block.call`.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a more general feature of passing a block to another block. If you pass a block as an argument to a block, do you have to pass it as a `Proc`?

Comment: @BobRodes You can't call a block. You can call a method, or a `Proc`. You can only pass a block in a method call, since a method call explicitly supports a block syntax: `foo { ... }`. You cannot pass a block in a `Proc` call, because a `Proc` call does not have a special syntax, but uses a method call to do it — and `#call` and `#[]` do not accept a block.

Comment: Right, I realize you can't call a block, and I saw the reason why the OP was getting the error was that, because of the semantics of `define_method`, he was trying to pass a block to a block instead of a method definition. So, I'm asking whether if you have `block1`, and want to pass it to `block2`, the way to do it is wrap `block1` in a `Proc` object first (by using `&whatever` in `block2`'s parameter list) and then `call` it from `block2` rather than using `yield`. In other words, is this a more general principle of which the OP's code is an example?

Comment: @BobRodes Again, I don't quite understand what you are asking, since "block" is not something you can have in a variable. If `block1` and `block2` are both `Proc`, then `block1[block2]` (or `block1.call(block2)`) works if `block2` accepts `|block|, and `block1[&block2]` works if `block2` accepts `|&block|`. However, this works: `class A; def m; puts "[#{yield}]"; end end; A.new.method(:m).to_proc.call { 4 }`. So you can call a `Proc` with a block (and have it `yield`) — as long as it was originally defined with `def`.

Comment: why does yield work in this example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module

Comment: Because `yield` is executing the block passed to `before`, which is the surrounding `def`.