# Wrapping a method, and passing an instance variable to it

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to define a macro that wraps another method, then pass the instance to the macro. Here's a contrived example...

```rb
module Wrapper
  def wrap(method_name, options: {})
    class_eval do
      new_method = "_wrap_#{method_name}"
      alias_method new_method, method_name

      define_method method_name do |*args, &block|
        # binding.pry
        puts "Options... #{options}"
        
        send new_method, *args, &block
      end
    end
  end
end

class Thing
  extend Wrapper

  class << self
    extend Wrapper

    def bar
      puts 'Bar!'
    end
    wrap :bar, options: -> { bar_options }

    private

    def bar_options
      { bar: 2 }
    end
  end

  def foo
    puts 'Foo!'
  end
  wrap :foo, options: -> { foo_options }

  private

  def foo_options
    { foo: 1 }
  end
end
```

So, I know I have access to the instance from within `define_method`, but I don't think I should have to create / rename / alias methods within my classes to conform to a module - I'd like to pass the config in, so to speak. I feel like `instance_exec/eval` is my friend, here, but I can't seem to get the incantation correct. I tried with passing a block to the code as well, but `yield` behaved the same as the proc. Maybe `binding`, but I can't wrap my head around that at all, for some reason.

This is from within the `define_method` call...

```
> Thing.new.foo
=> Options... #<Proc:0x00007fcb0782cfd8@(irb):24>
Foo!

> self.class
=> Thing

> self
=> #<Thing:0x00007fdfb78b88e8>

> options
=> #<Proc:0x00007fcb0782cfd8@(irb):24>

> options.call
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo_options` for Thing:Class

> foo_options
=> {:foo=>1}

> self.class.instance_eval &options
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo_options` for Thing:Class

> self.class.instance_exec &options
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo_options` for Thing:Class
```

I understand how a proc captures scope to use for later, so I can see how the use of a proc/lambda is incorrect here. When the class loads, the `wrap` method "wraps" the method and captures `foo_options` at the class level to be called for later - which doesn't exist at the class level. Calling `options: foo_options` does the same thing, just blows up on load.

Any bit helps... Thanks!

Comment: This example/use case doesn't make a ton of sense to me. You are calling `instance_eval` and `instance_exec` as class methods, but they're meant to be called on an instance (e.g., [instance_eval docu](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/BasicObject.html#instance_eval-method)). You're also overriding the definition of params that would automatically exist in a controller. Might want to check out the docu on [Concerns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and update this with a use case for a model.

Comment: Clarified. And yes, that's exactly the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I was so close... While within `define_method`, I have access to the instance, and can call `instance_exec` on self, instead of self.class! Also, there is a newer, preferred approach to wrapping methods since ruby 2.0.

```rb
module Wrapper
  def wrap(method_name, options: {})
    proxy = Module.new
    proxy.define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
      options = instance_exec(&options) if options.is_a?(Proc)
      target = is_a?(Module) ? "#{self}." : "#{self.class}#"
      puts "#{target}#{method_name} is about to be called. `wrap` options #{options}"
      super *args, &block
    end
    self.prepend proxy
  end
end
```

Output:

```sh
> Thing.new.foo
Thing#foo is about to be called. `wrap` options {:foo=>1}
Foo!
=> nil

> Thing.bar
Thing.bar is about to be called. `wrap` options {:bar=>2}
Bar!
=> nil
```

This is much cleaner than the "old way" that Sergio mentions in the comments. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219277/how-do-i-wrap-the-invocation-of-a-ruby-method-by-including-a-module) helped me out!

Another great benefit of this approach is that you can define the macro at the top of the file (where they belong, arguably).

Comment: BTW, using `alias_method` + replacing method is the old way. It was superseded by `Module.prepend`

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I know about both, but I copied this example from the Ruby source code for Gem::Deprecate.